# Dismiss non-application Window when Home button pressed

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I have a non-application window (i.e. a window with no activity context, that appears over other apps).  This window is technically a View which has been added using `WindowManager.addView()` and `TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR`.

I would like to remove this window when the Home button is pressed but it seems impossible to intercept the Home button press.

Is there any way to do this?

EDIT: My app does not have an `Activity` so cannot use any methods on the Activity class.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect when a user press Home button with:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint()

but you can't override system behaviour for that action.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have an `Activity` context.

Comment: If you have any view object you can always get a context from it: `mView.get context()`

Comment: But the context will not necessarily be an `Activity` context. My app does not have an `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

Below method used for enabling Home button key press event

```
 @Override
                public void onAttachedToWindow() {
                    super.onAttachedToWindow();
                    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);           
                }
```

And,

```
         @Override
            public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {     

                if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
                {
                   //The Code Want to Perform. 

                    //Leave Blank no code like back press method so by pressng home button it will not go to home

                    //This can be used for long press home button also
                }
                return true;
            }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `getWindow()` is a method on `Activity` and my app does not have an `Activity`. I have edited my question.

Comment: the windows is only a class or wat??

Comment: How you showing that window by inflating or by fragment

Comment: You can inflate a layout with any `Context` and then add it to the `WindowManager`. The status bar is an example of a `View` without an `Activity`.